# After login a terminal windows appear (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

After login there are the terminal windows that was used during the previous startup with working directory and command history suddenly re-appear when I log again or start up my computer. These windows were saved with working directories and command history from my previous session.

Help me to understand what the problem is please.

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: @MarkYisri, he is talking about the _session caching_ ability of Xubuntu that makes it possible to login and get all the previous session state invoke so one doesn't need to relaunch previously used apps just like when one wakes up from _hibernation_ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xubuntu and Ubuntu Studio (which both use the **xfce desktop**) there is the ability to save the *current session state* so that when you login again, apps from the previous session will automatically be launched into their previous state with the settings still intact.

You can *kill* or *stop* this behaviour by *deselecting* the option to *remember session* on your *session* log out or shutdown dialogue box that appears when your about to shutdown or logout of your computer. Its perfectly normal.

[image]

By selecting **Save session for future logins** you can quickly restore you system to its former state when you *login* or *start a new session*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look in system settings > session management and change the session save and restore options there.